# grid stack serialisation function not returning

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to serialise all the grids within my grid stack container, I can see the the values held within the elements properties however it does not seem to want to return the object properly.  When I perform my ajax POST request the widget data is not being assigned as my function is returning undefined.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        //store grid into a variable to be manipulated
        this.grid = $('.grid-stack').data('gridstack');

        //we create a saveGrid method to save attributes to the database
        this.save_grid = function () {
            this.serialized_data = _.map($('.grid-stack > .grid-stack-item:visible'), function (el) {
                el = $(el);
                var gridID = el.find('.grid-stack-item-content.ui-draggable-handle').first().attr('id');
                var node = el.data('_gridstack_node');
                return {
                    id: gridID,
                    x: node.x,
                    y: node.y,
                    width: node.width,
                    height: node.height
                };
            }, this);
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Dashboard/EditWidgets/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                widget: this.save_grid
            },
            success: function (dataset) {
            },
            failure: function (xhr, error) {
                console.log(xhr)
                console.log(error)
            },
            cache: false
        })
    };
```

Comment: I would take a look at your server logs. I think you are sending the function itself and not it's result. In other words, you are missing parenthesis: `widget: this.save_grid()`

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but did not seem to work, I tried setting the return to a variable but that still came back as undefined